# Django: Filter, list, session

Tags: python, django, session, implementation

I have some question on Django and how to use it to solve the problem below.
Suppose you have this two table
Products table

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
|  id   |   productName   | description   |  id_country     |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     |      x          | fzefzzezfz    |     1           |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
| 2     |      y          | zoinojnfze    |     1           |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
| 3     |      az         | ononbonoj     |     2           |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

country table

```
   -----------------------
    |  id    |    name     |
     -----------------------
    | 1      | france      |
     -----------------------
    | 2      | spain       |
     -----------------------
```

and these urls:

```
http://www.exemple.com/list/ (list all products)
http://www.exemple.com/add/ (add a new product)
http://www.exemple.com/detail/1 (print details about product with id=1)
```

What I want to do is to allow visitors of  website to set a filter for the duration of their navigation, so for every display of the product list 
only product from France or Spain will be displayed depending on the filter.

I could use french.exemple.com or spain.exemple.com to filter result but i dont want to ducplicate the code for every 
subdomain.

How would handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said it yourself in the question tags: use the session.

When the user chooses a country, set that value in the `request.session` dict; then, in each of your views, filter the products by that value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i got a question: there is no need the user to be logged before i use the request.session ?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your answer